# MATLAB GUIDE pushbutton effect when pushed and title size

Tags: matlab, button, push, matlab-guide

I have created a GUIDE script with 5 push buttons. Each button creates a different graph for given data. I would like every time I push one of the buttons (let's call it Button1), the button to look like it is pushed or maybe change color or title (I would prefer it to look pushed). When a different button(let's call it Button2) is pushed I want Button2 to look pushed and Button1 to look like it was initially.
Also when I plot figures and I use a title on top of the figure, GUIDE cuts the top part of the title. Is there any way to have the title on the inside of the figure or maybe closer to the top axis so that all of it is visible?

Answer (score 0):

1. (HARD) In the ButtonDownFcn callback for each button, put code that sets the BackgroundColor property.  (You can see all of the available properties for any control by choosing View/PropertyInspector in the main menu for GUIDE.)  Since you only have 5 buttons, the easiest way to get what you want is to just copy and paste code between them, with appropriate changes.

Pseudocode for Button 1:

```
Button1.BackgroundColor=PushedColor
Button2.BackgroundColor=NonpushedColor
etc for rest of buttons
```

1. (EASY)  Use a group of radio buttons instead.  They do what you want, automatically.

To reposition the title, you just change the Position property of the title's text box.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried the easy way. The way it works right now is that when I push button1 it shoes that I have pressed it but when i press button2, button1 still shows that it is pushed. Is there any way to have only one button pushed at a time? For example when i press button2 I want button1 to become unpushed.Thank you!